# java swing drag and drop jtable

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jframe, organizer

I want to create a schedule in a jframe using java. 
I have courses,classrooms,and faculty members. 
I want to drag them and drop something like jtable. 
how can I know which cell I use and how can I use drag and drop for them?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you have any code that doesn't work?

Comment: no,I don't.I am looking for a good example.It is part of my project but i don't have enough source.